# How to set conditions to avoid duplicate run for Tasks creation for a User Story

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

I created a Power Automate flow to create 9 tasks (Dev, Testing, and BA tasks) as a child for a new user story when it is assigned.

It works fine but it is getting duplicated every time when the story is assigned back from Unassigned to a resource.

I tried to get the count of related tasks for the user story before creating them but couldn't find any default conditions to get that.

Is there any other condition to set to avoid this duplicate task creations?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT - The proposed solution did not work as the required condition cannot be set by that option; so waiting for others to contribute to that query.

Comment: Hi All - The solution provided in https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-set-conditions-to-avoid-duplicate-Tasks-creation-for-a/td-p/289629/page/2 - worked for my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for the query to set a condition to check for the existing workitems before creating them has been provided by yashag2255 on the Power Automate forums:

> To get the work items related to the user story, you will have to send a HTTP request for that. But before sending this request -> Go to Azure DevOps -> Queries -> My Queries -> Create a new blank query and save it. (In this example let us say TestNew).
>
> After you have done this, in the flow under the trigger create an action as shown. Very carefully populate all the fields. (here 'yashTest' is my project, replace it with yours)
>
> ```
> Body : {
>      "name" : "TestNew",
>      "queryType" : "tree",
>      "wiql" : "SELECT [System.Id],[System.Title],[System.State] FROM workitemLinks WHERE([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' AND [Source].[System.Id] = )AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')AND ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task')MODE (Recursive)"
> }
> ```
>
> in the "wiql" near the [System.Id] = select the ID of the work item retrived from the trigger action (the original trigger request that has the id of the assigned work item)
>
> [image]
>
> Now, create a new string variable to get the query ID and put the foloowing expression in the expression editor and add it to the string value.
>
> ```
> body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_Azure_DevOps')['id']
> ```
>
> Now add another action: Get Query Results with the query ID in the previous step. This will fetch you a list of the work items related to the assigned work item. You can iterate thorough this to check if the items exist and if not create them with Create Work Item Action.
>
> [image]

Source: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-set-conditions-to-avoid-duplicate-Tasks-creation-for-a/td-p/289629